# Angular [object Object] error

Tags: javascript, angular

Recibo del api esos datos pero lo que esta dentro de user no me lo imprime salta error, y si solo pongo user imprime object. He probado parseando y mil cosas más pero no se como solucionarlo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se imprime en la web:

```
Timeline
[object Object] | @[object Object]
1611603664
Probando el Frontend

[object Object] | @[object Object]
1611415816
¡Primer tweet!
```

Comment: Agrega el código de cómo lo estás imprimiendo.

Comment: Dentro del html puedes usar el pipe `json`. De esta manera: `{{miArray | json}}`.

Comment: y el html?-....-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente ya alguien te dió una respuesta adecuada... lo que estas recibiendo como respuesta de la API, es un JSON, por tanto si quieres acceder a los datos:

Guarda la respuesta en una propiedad/variable publica, de tu class component, y luego accede a ella desde el view template o html component, asi:

```
{{ propiedad | json }}
```

NOTA:
Si quieres que el JSON se renderice de manera apropiada, usa la etiqueta pre de HTML así:

```
<pre>{{ propiedad | json }}</pre>
```

Saludos bro!.

Comment: Efectivamente, gracias por la ayuda y el consejo de la etiqueta <pre> que desconocía. Saludos!